# How to fit an image in a circle button properly in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

The images I have been adding are not fitting properly in the circular shape.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnGYL.png) is the image for reference

And this is the code for reference

```
      Container(
      child:Material(
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.black26,
          onTap: (){},
          child: Ink.image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/'+ Name),
            height: 60 ,
            width: 60,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ),Text(String),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fit property of Ink.child

1st way : Use fit: BoxFit.cover, for center cropped image

Or else

2nd way : Use fit: BoxFit.fill, to stretch the image

```
Container(
      child:Material(
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.black26,
          onTap: (){},
          child: Ink.image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/'+ Name),
            fit: BoxFit.cover, //Add this line for center crop or use 2nd way
            height: 60 ,
            width: 60,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ),Text(String),
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use
[CircleAvatar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html)

here is the demo code

```
CircleAvatar(
                radius: 20.0,
                child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.network(
                        'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0sCAvrW1yFi0UYMgTZb113I0SwtW0dpby8Q&usqp=CAU')),
              ),
```

though I can't open your example image, I guess if you use Circle Avatar it will work

Comment: I did the circle avatar as yo suggested but the images are not yet adjusted, they are getting cut from above. And now I have edited the question again as well with the image link.

Comment: did you use backgroundImage: 
ok if this is not working then I'm changing my ans please look at it and let me know it's working or not

Comment: This changed ans will not work because I want an Image in proper circle which is a button as well

Comment: use inkwell in parent then it will work as a button and and my given example will show you circle image.